# asp.net framework plugin application

Tags: asp.net, plugins, frameworks, mef

I really don't know if someone else has already written down a question similar to this one. I searched on google but maybe i don't know the right tag to search for.

I'd like to project and develop a web-based framework with a number of functionalities like a cms (user management, be able to write articles and so on). The focal point is that i'd like to architect it allowing administrator to activate or disactivate more functionalities by adding a new plugin (ie: he could do that by uploading an xml - as joomla does - or by clicking on 'activate' button - as wordpress does.)

Does exist any tutorial or open source project? Is MEF the way i have to go into?

Answer (score 1):

Look for existing solutions. Things like Umbraco ( http://umbraco.org) and N2CMS ( http://umbraco.org) and Microsoft Orchard ( http://orchard.codeplex.com) and others are simple open source (not complicated) and should all be good things to start your project from them and develop any functionality you need that doesn't exist as a per their existing plugin architecture.

This will save you not just from re-inventing the wheel but also save a lot of time and effort in stuff that is already out there.